# Error while installing Mono on FreeBSD 10.3 (No address record repository FreeBSD has no meta file)

Tags: mono, freebsd

Can anybody please help me with installing mono on FreeBSD 10.3 version?

While Installing using `pkg install mono` I get an error as

> pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/quarterly/meta.txz: No address record
>   repository FreeBSD has no meta file, using default settings
>   pkg: http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/FreeBSD:10:amd64/quarterly/packagesite.txz: No address record
>   Unable to update repository FreeBSD

Please suggest me the steps to install Mono on FreeBSD since I'm new to FreeBSD.

Comment: I get those errors when the server has no internet access, particularly DNS resolution.

Comment: Can you please let me know how the command line gets to know this url to be accessed when i try to install mono. There must be a config file from which it takes the above mentioned url

Comment: It comes from `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf`, but why do you need that. The problem is that your DNS servers aren't set.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me. Just can you let me know how to host ASP.NET MVC Web application on freebsd. The way i got is through using Mono but I'm stuck up with its installation and configuration to host the web site. I have developed my application in VS2015 IDE on windows and want to publish it (via FTP) on freebsd. Any help would be greatful since I'm stuck up for almost over a week. Thanks in advance